# Eslint: Parsing error: ts.createWatchCompilerHost is not a function

Tags: typescript, eslint

Why I get this error?
My config:

```
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "project": "tsconfig.json",
    "tsconfigRootDir": ".",
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module"
  }


"devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.7.0",
    "eslint": "^7.4.0",
    "typescript": "2.5.2"
  }
```

with this config I get error: **Parsing error: ts.createWatchCompilerHost is not a function**

If I change typescript version since **3.3.1** everything works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ts.createWatchCompilerHost` was introduced in v3. As stated in the [@typescript-eslint/parser Readme](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint#supported-typescript-version):

> The version range of TypeScript currently supported by this parser is >=3.3.1 <3.10.0.

I would suggest either upgrading TypeScript or using [TSLint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/) as @typescript-eslint/parser does not support < 3.